# Semicolon escaping in postgresql on Windows

Tags: postgresql

I have an `sql` script defining a function in `create_database_function.sql` file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_display_count(in_host_id int, in_host_owner_id int, in_date_ date) RETURNS void as $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE display_count set display_count = display_count + 1 
    WHERE host_id = in_host_id AND host_owner_id = in_host_owner_id AND date_ = in_date_;
    IF FOUND THEN
        RETURN;
    END IF;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO display_count (host_id, host_owner_id, date_, display_count) VALUES (in_host_id, in_host_owner_id, in_date_, 1);
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        UPDATE display_count set display_count = display_count + 1
                WHERE host_id = in_host_id AND host_owner_id = in_host_owner_id AND date_ = in_date_;
    END;
    RETURN;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to execute in on **Windows**. To do so, I run a usual command:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d database -f create_database_function.sql
```

But this script gave me a huge number of syntax errors. An hour-long googling didn't bear fruit. But I went on tinkering with this script and eventually found the problem.

The solution was to prepend all semicolon `;` signs with backslash `\`.

Though this solves the problem, it introduces another one. I work on the project with another guy. But he works on Linux. In his case the script should be without `\` before semicolons.

So, why do I need to prepend `;` with `\` on Windows? Can this be somehow avoided or done another way?

I googled for it a lot and haven't found any similar problem.

---

#### Update

The output when I use `\;` instead of `;`:

```
C:\Xubuntu_shared\pixel\pixel\src\main\scripts>psql -h localhost -U postgres -d
pixel_test -f create_database_function.sql
Password:
CREATE FUNCTION
```

The output with errors when I execute the script without backslash escaping:

```
C:\Xubuntu_shared\pixel\pixel\src\main\scripts>psql -h localhost -U postgres -d
pixel_test -f create_database_function.sql
Password:
psql:create_database_function.sql:4: ERROR:  unterminated dollar-quoted string a
t or near "$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE display_count set display_count = display_count + 1
    WHERE host_id = in_host_id AND host_owner_id = in_host_owner_id AND date_ =
in_date_;" at character 121
psql:create_database_function.sql:6: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF" at cha
racter 5
psql:create_database_function.sql:7: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF" at cha
racter 9
psql:create_database_function.sql:9: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT" at
 character 19
psql:create_database_function.sql:12: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION
" at character 5
psql:create_database_function.sql:13: WARNING:  there is no transaction in progr
ess
COMMIT
psql:create_database_function.sql:14: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN" a
t character 5
psql:create_database_function.sql:15: WARNING:  there is no transaction in progr
ess
COMMIT
psql:create_database_function.sql:17: ERROR:  unterminated dollar-quoted string
at or near "$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;" at character 1
```

Other information that may be important:

`create_database_function.sql` encoding is `UTF-8`, without `BOM`. Line ending is in Windows format.

---

#### Update 2

Version

```
pixel=> SELECT version();
                           version
-------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit
(1 row)


pixel=>
```

---

#### Update 3

Output from `output of select name, setting, source from pg_settings where source <> 'default';` command:

```
Oleg@OLEG-PC /C/Xubuntu_shared/pixel/pixel/src/main/scripts (pixel-dev2)
$ psql -U postgres
Password:
Welcome to psql.exe 7.4.6, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
       \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help on internal slash commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

Warning: Console codepage (866) differs from windows codepage (1251)
         8-bit characters will not work correctly. See PostgreSQL
         documentation "Installation on Windows" for details.

postgres=# select name,setting,source from pg_settings where source <> 'default'
;
            name            |                       setting
   |        source
----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
---+----------------------
 config_file                | C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/postgresql.co
nf | override
 data_directory             | C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/data
   | override
 DateStyle                  | ISO, MDY
   | configuration file
 default_text_search_config | pg_catalog.english
   | configuration file
 hba_file                   | C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf
   | override
 ident_file                 | C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/pg_ident.conf
   | override
 lc_collate                 | C
   | override
 lc_ctype                   | C
   | override
 lc_messages                | C
   | configuration file
 lc_monetary                | C
   | configuration file
 lc_numeric                 | C
   | configuration file
 lc_time                    | C
   | configuration file
 listen_addresses           | *
   | configuration file
 log_destination            | stderr
   | configuration file
 log_line_prefix            | %t
   | configuration file
 log_timezone               | Europe/Moscow
   | configuration file
 logging_collector          | on
   | configuration file
 max_connections            | 100
   | configuration file
 max_stack_depth            | 2048
   | environment variable
 port                       | 5432
   | configuration file
 server_encoding            | UTF8
   | override
 shared_buffers             | 4096
   | configuration file
 TimeZone                   | Europe/Moscow
   | configuration file
 transaction_deferrable     | off
   | override
 transaction_isolation      | read committed
   | override
 transaction_read_only      | off
   | override
 wal_buffers                | 128
   | override
(27 rows)
```

Comment: What exactly are the error messages ? Please add them to the question. If there are too many, only show the first one(s).

Comment: @wildplasser I have added script output

Comment: PostgreSQL version? (Should go without saying.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Added version to the question

Comment: This is completely wierd. Either the editor does strange things, or the build is plain wrong (I would not expect it to be built with a C++ compiler, BTW) I would start by hexdumping the SQL file and check it near the semicolons. if **the same** SQL file executes fine on a unix machine, the build is definitely wrong.

Comment: Strange. Does it make any difference if the text has "unix" or  "windows" eol? (\r -> \r\n)? And are you sure that the psql client is the same version as the server?

Comment: I don't have any problems with semicolons in SQL scripts under Windows. And I certainly don't need to escape them.

Comment: On my windows 7 dev machine I get "PostgreSQL 9.2.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit". Using binary installer provided by EnterpriseDB, so I don't think there's any reason getting hung up on the C++ compiler.

Comment: @leonbloy I remember installing psql separately. So the strange behavior may be connected with it. I will check tomorrow and answer here.

Comment: @wildplasser It is *absolutely normal* for Pg on Windows to be built with Microsoft Visual C++. That's just the product name; it compiles C files in pure C mode and C++ files in C++ mode.

Comment: That's ... completely insane. If you were feeding the file in on standard input (or as a here-document if cmd.exe supports them), eg `psql .... < the-file` I could almost imagine the shell doing some kind of bizarre metacharacter substitution, but not when `psql` is just reading the file normally. Please show output of `select name, setting, source from pg_settings where source <> 'default';` . Also, what language is your Windows install in and what's the default text encoding (codepage)? Type `chcp`<enter> in your command prompt to get the current codepage.

Comment: Does setting the unicode codepage in cmd.exe help? (Stabbing wildly in the dark here). See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN85435

Comment: @leonbloy Postgres frontend is of version 7.4.6 As I remember, I installed if from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/psql/

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm unable to launch this command `psql .... < the-file` as if sql data is supplied from stdin (not via `-f the-file`), psql bypasses password prompt, nor does password read it from `C:\Documents and Settings\Oleg\Application Data\postgresql\pgpass.conf` (I tried using `-W` key to no avail).

Comment: @CraigRinger `chcp` gives `866` as codepage in command prompt. But I don't see how it can affect psql work, as all codepages share codes for English symbols and only differ in codes for Cyrillic.

Comment: @CraigRinger Changing encoding with `chcp 1252` command and following launching `psql -h localhost -U postgres -d
pixel_test -f create_database_function.sql` produces the same errors.

Comment: **psql.exe 7.4.6**. Really? That is completely outdated, obsolete and unsupported. You have to use `psql.exe` that matches your server version (at least the major version number should match).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yep, that'll be the problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you! You are so right! The problems were connected with the version of psql client. I deleted the obsolete one and added path to the one shipped with Postgres package to path variable. Now script works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may encounter this rare problem.

It is related to Postgres server and client versions mismatch. I were using Server of version `9.2.3` and Client of version `7.4.6`.

Is important to mention that Postgres installer for Windows already includes `psql` client. So there is no need to install another one.

I don't remember exactly why I installed a separate client, but I guess it was because `psql` didn't start from console. I think it could be cured by rebooting Windows after PosrgreSQL isntallation (as a lot of problems are solved with this OS this way) or manually adding path to `psql.exe` to environment path variable.

So, if you face the same problem, check the version of Server and Client. And if they don't match, set the path environment variable to the correct client from original PosgreSQL shipping.

Comment: `psql` wasn't starting from the console (`cmd.exe`, Command Prompt) because it wasn't in your `PATH`. You can add it to your `PATH` in your user environment variables, use an explicit path, or just use the psql entry in the Start menu.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yeah. I have already added it to `PATH`. In my case it's essential because I need to spawn `psql` commands from scripts.

Comment: I think that, more than a server-client mismatch, the problem was that the client was very old. It's no problem using different versions of psql client and server, in general. Though, normally, you should use that which comes with the server installation, if you are running it locally.

Comment: @ovgolovin Er... you can launch `psql` from scripts without having it on the `PATH`. Try `%PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\psql.exe` (adjusting for version).

Comment: @CraigRinger I work on the project not alone. The other member uses Linux. Are you sure there is %PROGRAMFILES% on Linux? :)

Comment: @ovgolovin Er, no. I was referring to the *windows* path, since I thought that was where you were having the problem. On Linux you just use the `PATH` env var and `psql`, or if it isn't on the path you specify the path directly, eg, `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/psql`. I think I see what you're getting at now - you are writing scripts that run under both Linux and Windows and don't want to have to specify a different explicit path to psql on both hosts. In that case, you can either (a) source a per-machine config file or (b) add it to the PATH.

Comment: @CraigRinger I choose (b)!